# Do Indian citizens need a transit visa to connect in Rome (Fiumicino airport)?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, italy

I am resident of India (Indian passport). I am travelling from Israel (Tel Aviv) to  Rome (Fiumicino) on El Al Airlines, and from Rome (Fiumicino), I fly to India (Delhi) on Air India Airlines.

The connection time between the two flights is 3 hours.

Do I need to get a transit visa or is it not required?

Comment: @Kuba The Problem is taht it doesn't state which Airports have a Transit corridor and which ones do not

Comment: Is the trip in one booking or two separate ones?

Comment: one booking..single ticket

Comment: @PriyankaUddandarao Good, then no visa needed :)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&selDest=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20destination%28s%29%20above&TR=IT&selTrans=Italy&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of onward tickets for a max.
>   transit of 48 hours through Milan (MXP), Rome (FCO) or Venice (VCE)

So if the trip is in one booking, you do **not** Need a visa. Otherwise you do.

Answer (score 0):

As it's stated on [the website](http://www.esteri.it/mae/en/ministero/servizi/stranieri/ingressosoggiornoinitalia/visto_ingresso/paesi_soggetti_visto_transito_aeroportuale.html) of Italian Ministry of Foreign Affairs and International Cooperation:

> The citizens of the following countries are required to obtain visas
>   for transit through Italian airports:
>
> Afghanistan, Bangladesh, Democratic Republic of Congo, Eritrea,
>   Ethiopia, Ghana, Iran, Iraq, Nigeria, Pakistan, Somalia, Sri Lanka,
>   Senegal, Syria

As India is not on this list, **you don't need a transit visa in Italy**.

Comment: Only applies to Milan-Malpensa, Rome-Fiumicino and Venice-Marco Polo. The others lack Transit corridors, so if OP were connecting in, say, Milan-Linate, they'd Need a visa

Comment: But why then it's not mentioned in the official website, which is IMO supposed to be the first source of information. Even if I had any problems in other airports, I would have shown them these website.

Comment: Because they lack transit corridors and thus everyone has to clear immigration, for which at least a short-stay Schengen visa is always required for visa nationals. And just saying, Timatic is what you should consult first when it comes to air travel.